# Why I am getting an unknown error in pom.xml file when I add the spring-boot-starter-security dependency?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, maven

I got an unknown error after adding  the **spring-boot-starter-security dependency** to pom.xml file.I tried using maven--->update project option in eclipse too,but the error is remaining.I am 100 % sure that the error is related with the above mentioned dependency,because when I removed it the problem solved.

**pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hasiya.springboot.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>firstSpringBootApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>firstSpringBootApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: exactly the same pom worked for me. can you create a sample project and post in github to reproduce the error?

Comment: what happens if you try calling `mvn clean package` from the command line?

Comment: @Daniele nothing happens when I run mvn clean with eclipse

Comment: Not just `clean`, but `clean package`.

Comment: Without the command line output, it is hard to help you.

Comment: @HasinduDahanayake Eclipse emulates Maven.  You must be certain that your maven configuration is as expected first, by using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can update Maven project to solve this problem.[image]

Comment: It would helpful to have more detail on how to start an update, to give context to the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

go to project,right click ,find maven ,click on it ,go to update project, check the checkbox of force update.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:
https://github.com/sarl/sarl/issues/921
which is basically adding this to your pom.xml file:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
```